# Overlapping absolute and/or relative positionned divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, markup

```
    <div id="headContainer">

        <div id="blackBar">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="../Images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo" />
                <div id="clientSettings">
                    <div id="settingsContainer">
                        <ul>
                            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="endSession" OnClick="endSession_Click" Text="Exit" runat="server" /></li>
                            <li>not available</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="clientProfile"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#clientSettings').click(function () {
                    $('#settingsContainer').toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <div id="grayBar">

        </div>

    </div>
```

Alright, So as you might guess from above, I am trying to show `#settingsContainer` once `#clientSettings` has been clicked by using jQuery. I am able to achieve that with the `.toggle()` method. However, `#settingsContainer` needs to overlap `#grayBar`.

Please see below the CSS:

## headContainer:

```
#headContainer 
{
    top                 : 0;
    left                : 0;
    width               : 100%;
    height              : 100px;
    position            : fixed; <- or relative doesn't matter.
    z-index             : 1;
}

#headContainer div#grayBar
{
    top                 : 0;
    left                : 0;
    position            : relative; <- or fixed doesn't matter.
    width               : 100%;
    height              : 50px;
    background-color    : #f1f1f1;
    z-index             : 1;
}
```

## clientSettings + settingsContainer:

```
#headContainer div#blackBar div#clientSettings
{
    float               : left;
    position            : relative;
    width               : 25px;
    height              : 50px;
    background-image    : url('../Images/Icons/endSession.png');
    background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    background-position : center center;
}

#headContainer div#blackBar div#clientSettings:hover 
{
    cursor              : pointer;
    background-color    : #636363;  
}

#headContainer div#blackBar div#clientSettings #settingsContainer
{  
    position            : relative; <- tried using absolute instead.
    top                 : 50px;
    left                : 0;
    padding             : 50px;
    background-color    : Green;
    z-index             : 99999; <- doesn't really matter.
}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to have `#settingsContainer` overlap its parents and everything else while keeping it as a child of `#clientSettings.`

Thank you.

Comment: +1: I wish all users would put this amount of effort into their questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `float:left` in `#clientSettings`, floated elements comes out of the browser's draw flow, so they start behave similar to `position:absolute` elements. You can either remove `float:left` or start using z-index (in both `#settingsContainer` and `#clientSettings`). Here is working  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/podlipensky/2YrhR/4/) with your code.

Comment: Could I wrap both elements up in another div and apply 'clearfix' on that div? Do you think that's a proper solution too?

Comment: what do you mean under 'clearfix'? could you show example on the  jsfiddle?

Comment: Well it's nothing really just a method I found earlier about clearing the floating elements which would sort of align everything up. http://jsfiddle.net/8Enzp/

Comment: I can't get rid of float:left it would ruin the design, since the main direction is rtl. I tried adding the .clearfix class, also couldn't resolve this.

Comment: Removing position:relative and top/left from #grayBar did the trick. I'm still going to accept your answer because it explains a solution also because you took the time to answer me. Thanks!